# Set the height of a div to the same as a PHP value

Tags: php, html, css

I am attempting to make a small custom graph, and I would like to set the height of each part of the graph to a PHP variable.

I have a container with a fixed height:

```
.container {
   height: 200px;
}
```

I then have 3 additional divs within the container, lets say 'a', 'b' and 'c'. The values of a, b, and c are all taken from a database, so their height needs to be dynamic. In PHP, I get the weight of each div through simple math: `$a_weight = $a / ($a + $b + $c)` (for a). I would then like to set the height of `div a` to that weight. So, `div a` would be `$a_height = $a_weight * 200`. For example, if `$a_weight = 30%`, the resulting height of `div a` would be `$a_height = 60px` (.30*200).

Is this possible to do? Can I then do something like:

```
<div class="a" height=".$a_height."></div>
```

If not, what would be the best practice in order to get a value from a database (mysql), and set the height of an element proportionally based on that element.

Comment: Like this? [CSS maintain div aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @sdcr no sorry. I am looking to change the aspect based on a php value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an AJAX request to fire off a PHP script that grabs data from your database, then returns that data back to the client.  You could then use the returned data to style your HTML elements with JavaScript/jQuery.